How to ground without using the car's chassis and metal frame?
I'm designing and prototyping hardware electronics, see here
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/AeonLabs-AI-Volvo-MKII-Open-Hardware/wiki , and I want to separate the ground line from the chassis and the frame of the car.
The main motive is to protect my electronics from some kind of electromagnetic attack, while parked and also when driving.
the second protection I want to install is a high voltage circuit that is capable of detecting an EM discharge, warning about it to the driver, and log, while at the same time is able to handle it and discharge it in a safe kind of way.

I never rely on chassis or frame as ground - I always run two leads back to the fuse block and then the battery. As for the rest, it all depends on just what kind of an EMP you are concerned about.

nice. I never thought of adding a fuse to the ground wire. Good one!

Running a separate wire will result in the opposite of what you're trying to accomplish. Everything else in the car is tied to chassis ground, while your system will be referenced to the same ground, but via a long cable with resistance and inductance.
If there was an EMP attack, or more likely a lightning strike, chassis ground potential would change, but the ground going into your device would equalize slower relative to well-bonded devices. This creates a difference in ground potential between your device and other devices, and therefore damage at the sensitive digital pins where they interface.
The purpose of grounding is to keep everything at the same potential, and the best way to do it is with as much metal as possible: thick ground braids and the heavy metal chassis of the car.

That's not good for me. I need to have a dedicated thick ground wire for all the electronics, and a purpose hardware electronics capable of discharging any accumulated electricity in the chassis and frame of a car.
